# Cannot access ubuntu docker container

Tags: ubuntu, docker, macos

How do I access a docker containers web interface. I pulled down the latest ubuntu container with `docker pull ubuntu`. I then did `docker run -it ubuntu bash` and installed the python dependencies to run a flask app from within the container. I am trying to run the [this](https://github.com/mmumshad/simple-webapp-flask) flask app for testing.

How do I now access the containers flask application from the host system? When I do docker inspect on the container I don't see any references to an IP address.

The host I am using is macOS High Sierra and running docker version 19.03.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to publish port to link the host port to your container port, this is the most common way. Don't know flask but this should work

`docker run -it --publish 80:80 ubuntu bash`

`--publish` (or -p) will allow you to map a host port to a running container port
https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/#published-ports

You also can add a docker network and use the IP address of the container.
https://docs.docker.com/network/